# cannot use Html helper in partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, http-get, html.textboxfor

**Background**

I have following method in my controller

```
[HttpGet]
 public ActionResult GetModulePropertyName(string moduleTypeValue)
 {
    var moduleKindId = _repository.GetModuleKindId(moduleTypeValue);
    var modulePropertyNames = _repository.GetModuleKindPropertyNames(moduleKindId);
    return PartialView(modulePropertyNames);
  }
```

`modulePropertyNames` may contain `List of strings` of could be null.

**What I want to do**

I want to create text box for each string that is passed to Partial view with placeholder or label as string, user will type some text there which I will later retrieve.

**What I've been doing**

I'm doing following right now, but it says cannot resolve symbol TextboxFor

```
@foreach (var names in Model)
{
  <div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(names, new {@placeholder = names})</div>
}
```

Here is **web.config** of the area i've been working on

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Where is that file? Show us `Views\Web.config`.

Comment: It is inside the Area that I've been working on. The controller and view i'm referring are in the same Area called Hardware. Do i still need to post my web.config of my web.config of my area?

Comment: Show us `Areas\Hardware\Views\Web.config`.  It probably doesn't have the Html extensions namespace

Comment: i've added it to the end

Comment: as far as i see it has namespace `System.Web.Mvc.Html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.TextBoxFor` taking `Expression<Func<List<Model>>, TProperty>` as a first argument.
Try to use it another way:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(name => name[i], new {@placeholder = names})
}
```

Or use `Html.TextBox()`:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBox("name[" + i + "]", Model[i], new {@placeholder = names})
}
```

Comment: worked but says lambda expression is not applicable to string :(

Comment: If you are using lambda - you should use Html.TextBoxFor, otherwise you need Html.TextBox. Please take a look at my updated answer.